# Gitlab repository vs project vs submodule

Tags: gitlab

I started exploring Gitlab for version control management and I got an issue at the first step itsself. When ever I create a project its creating a new repository. I have few webapplications  which are independent to each other. In that case do I need to use different repository for every project.

What I am looking for is what is what and when to use what but not able to find what is repository and what is project in gitlab website as well as through other sources as well.

Also I came across a term submodule, when can it be used. Can I create one global project and have all the webapplications as different submodules.

Can any one please help me in understanding the difference between those 3 and when to use what based on their intended way of usage. Also please help me by pointing to a good learning site where I can get the information of doing basic version control operations in gitlab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Gitlab manages **projects**: a [project has many features](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/workflow/project_features.md) in addition of the Git repo it includes:

- issues: powerful, but lightweight issue tracking system.
- merge requests: you can review and discuss code before it is merged in the branch of your code.
- wiki: separate system for documentation, built right into GitLab
- snippets: Snippets are little bits of code or text.

So fear each repo you create, you get additional features in its associated project.
And you can [manage users](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/raketasks/user_management.md) associated to that project.

See [GitLab documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc) for more.

The Git repo and [Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are pure Git notions.

In your case, a submodule might not be needed, unless you want a convenient way to remember the exact versions of different webapp repo, recorded in one parent repo.
But if that is the case, then yes, you can create one global project and have all the webapplications as different submodules.
Each of those submodules would have their own GitLab project (and Git repo).